# Convert a (-ve) number to a (+ve) or absolute

Tags: conversion, updates, sql

How do I update a field in a SQL table to change a neg to a pos. (Multiply *-1)

I have some data that was loaded using a mapper tool. Unfortunately the data should have been - and was +. The software takes the data *-1 and that is the value. In this case it is monthly usage.

So I loaded it as absolute and the mapper inverted the numbers showing negative usage in my system now. I would like to update the table to show correct numbers.

Comment: Step 1. Fix your Caps lock.

Comment: Run an update command via SQL. The Update command does take math fromulas if your data is numeric.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT. I've fixed it for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an update statement to update your fields accordingly. Since I have no idea your table names or column names here is a simple example of doing that:

```
UPDATE table SET datafield = (datafield * -1) WHERE some_condition;
```

If you have a certain situation when you want this done, just edit the "some_condition"